# access of array at module scope, from thread in another module, causes error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Tags: vb.net

When thread in one module accesses an array of forms in 2nd module, array reference is now 'nothing' and crashes with error: 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'

Here is Form template with the array...

```
Public Class Antenna_Window_Template
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''   CONSTANTS   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    public const MAX_ANTENNAS = 8
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''   VARIABLES   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''

    public antenna_graph_Windows( MAX_ANTENNAS )  as Antenna_Window_Template



    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''   C O D E   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''



End Class
```

Here is array initialization...

```
Public Class Main_Window

    Private Sub Main_Window_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load



        for antenna = 1 to MAX_ANTENNAS
            ' antenna_graph_Windows.add( new Antenna_Window_Template )
            with Antenna_Window_Template
             .antenna_graph_Windows( antenna ) = new Antenna_Window_Template
             .antenna_graph_Windows( antenna ).text &= antenna

             .antenna_graph_Windows( antenna ).show
            end with
        Next

    End Sub
Private Sub Button_start_capture_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button_start_capture.Click
    aa = Antenna_Window_Template.antenna_graph_Windows ' <<< ARRAY OK


    if CheckBox_simulate_embedded.Checked 
        Embedded_Simulation.start_capture_session()     
    aa = Antenna_Window_Template.antenna_graph_Windows' <<< ARRAY OK
        return
    End If
    Embedded_Serial_Interface.start_capture_session()       

End Sub
```

When run, the 8 antenna windows successfully show.

When START button pressed, here is thread trying to access it...

```
public Module Embedded_Simulation
    dim embedded_communication_thread as thread



    sub start_capture_session
        aa = Antenna_Window_Template.antenna_graph_Windows  '<<<<<<<<<< ARRAY OK UP TO THIS POINT
        ' Start communication thread:
            embedded_communication_thread = new Thread( AddressOf run_embedded_communication )
            embedded_communication_thread.Start()               
    End sub    


    sub run_embedded_communication
        aa = Antenna_Window_Template.antenna_graph_Windows  ' AT THIS POINT, ARRAY HAS THE 8 ELEMENTS, BUT EACH POINTS TO "nothing"
        with Antenna_Window_Template
        do  
            ' Simulate sample from embedded

            simulate_sample( simulation_value_I, simulation_value_Q )

        aa = Antenna_Window_Template.antenna_graph_Windows

            ' Update graph of each antenna window:
            for antenna_index = 1 to MAX_ANTENNAS step 1



                .antenna_graph_Windows( antenna_index ).Chart_antenna_window.Series("sample_point_I").Points.AddY( simulation_value_I )   ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  CRASHES: : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
                .antenna_graph_Windows( antenna_index ).Chart_antenna_window.Series("sample_point_Q").Points.AddY( simulation_value_Q )
            next

            . . .
        Loop
        ' End thread:
        end with
    End sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a module use another class.  Maybe this is what it should look like...

```
Public Class Antenna_Window_Template
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''   CONSTANTS   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Public Shared ReadOnly MAX_ANTENNAS As Integer = 8
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''   VARIABLES   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Public antenna_graph_Windows As List(Of Antenna_Window_Template)
    Public Shared isInited As Boolean = False

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''   C O D E   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    Public Sub New()
        If Not isInited Then
            isInited = True
            Me.antenna_graph_Windows = New List(Of Antenna_Window_Template)
            For idx As Integer = 1 To MAX_ANTENNAS
                antenna_graph_Windows.Add(New Antenna_Window_Template)
            Next
            isInited = False
        End If
    End Sub

    Public Iterator Function AllAGW() As IEnumerable(Of Antenna_Window_Template)
        For Each agw As Antenna_Window_Template In Me.antenna_graph_Windows
            Yield agw
        Next
    End Function

    ''''''''''''''''''''''''''' O T H E R    C O D E   '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
End Class

Public Class Embedded_Simulation
    Private embedded_communication_thread As Task
    Private aa As Antenna_Window_Template

    Public Sub New(some_Antenna_Window_Template As Antenna_Window_Template)
        Me.aa = some_Antenna_Window_Template
    End Sub

    Public Sub start_capture_session()
        ' Start communication thread:
        embedded_communication_thread = Task.Run(Sub()
                                                     Me.run_embedded_communication()
                                                 End Sub)
    End Sub

    Private Sub run_embedded_communication()
        Do
            ' Simulate sample from embedded

            ' simulate_sample(simulation_value_I, simulation_value_Q)

            ' Update graph of each antenna window:
            For Each AWT As Antenna_Window_Template In Me.aa.AllAGW
                'AWT.Chart_antenna_window.Series("sample_point_I").Points.AddY(simulation_value_I)   ' <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<  CRASHES: : 'Object reference not set to an instance of an object.'
                'AWT.Chart_antenna_window.Series("sample_point_Q").Points.AddY(simulation_value_Q)
            Next
            Thread.Sleep(500) 'simulate delay
        Loop
        ' End thread:
    End Sub
End Class
```

And then it is used like this

```
    Dim awtData As New Antenna_Window_Template
    Dim embSim As New Embedded_Simulation(awtData)
    embSim.start_capture_session()
```

Just guessing based on the limited info.

Modules have specific uses, as shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/module-statement#remarks), and this does not seem to meet those.